# "Allow" Button for flash content cannot be clicked in Mac Chrome

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, xhtml, swfobject

I'm using Mac Chrome 8.0.552.237

It seems like whenever I embed flash content in html and open it in chrome when my flash content requests camera access and i need to click "allow" button in the dialog it never recognizes the click. It works fine in firefox. I just simply can't understand why it wont work in chrome. I use swfobject, and i used http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html to make the html code just to make sure i wasn't making any mistakes.

any ideas what I could be doing that causes it to not let me click allow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.registerObject("MyFlashContent", "10.1.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="480" height="800" id="MyFlashContent" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="MyFlashContent.swf" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="MyFlashContent.swf" width="480" height="800" align="middle">
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Since it seems like the issue might actually be with my actionscrip code, i'll post how i attached the camera.

```
var youCam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
you_cam.attachCamera(youCam);
```

as you can see I have it attached about as simple as it can get, I actually have this right at the top of my code to place the camera on the stage. This works fine when i test it, and it works fine in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but because of the large size of the swf canvas, i learned in chrome i had to click the resize corner of the browser and make the window small and then bring it back to the regular size then it would work. no idea why, but this was only hapening in chrome. i fixed the issue by making the overall size of my swf smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the css display property to 'inline-block'

I had a similar problem. I was using a swf webcam plugin and, on Chrome 21 only, it was not allowing users to click allow. I ended up fixing it by changing it's css 'display' from 'block' to 'inline-block'.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue like this before, but it wasn't the browser nor the embedding, it was the example code for enabling the webcam (I think this code even came from the Adobe live docs ffs). The issue was that the camera polling already started, before the allow button was pushed. The polling (some augmented reality experiment) was so heavy, that the allow button only registered the click every 1 in 10 times or so. By putting of the camera polling till after the status-event returned with camera.muted == false, I solved my problem.

Maybe it's worth a try. Cheers, EP

Edit: Code example for the handler

```
var youCam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
youCam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, handleCameraStatus);

...

private function handleCameraStatus(e:StatusEvent):void {
    if (e.code == "Camera.Unmuted") {
        you_cam.attachCamera(youCam);
    } else if (e.code == "Camera.Muted") {
        // display message so the user might try again.
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm. I was thinking maybe something like this. well, my app is a video chat app, so right off the bat im setting up the camera and attaching it to a video box. any idea how I can let it wait to load or something? Maybe just put it at the bottom of my code?

Comment: edit: I just tried assigning the camera to attach when a button was clicked, and it still wouldn't let me click the allow access button. Could you possibly show me what you mean?

Comment: I have it wrapped in a giant puremvc webcam proxy (https://gist.github.com/4d859f0c030342a682d4), if you by accident use puremvc, it might help you. Otherwise let's try step by step. Did you listen for the StatusEvent.STATUS before calling the video.attachCamera()?

Comment: interesting, yeah i learned how to setup the camera from some adobe doc. I didn't know I needed to wait for a status event. I updated above to show the code i used. it was only 2 lines, really simple.

Comment: Everything you've said makes sense. I tried this, and it works the way you intend. But, it still doesnt allow me to click allow. Which is driving me nuts because I have another project i did where i attached the camera the same way and it lets me click allow. but no matter what i do with this one it wont let me click allow. i cant figure it out. thanks for trying

Comment: Frustrating! Sorry man, I wouldn't know what else it could be. Only blind firing comes to mind, like "have you tried dynamic publishing, instead of static?" but logic tells me this shouldn't make a difference. Please do let know when/if you find this out.